# Meta-analysis: Correlated controls, correlated treatment: How to specify variance-covariance?

Tags: meta-analysis, covariance-matrix, independence

**Goal**

The goal is meta-analysis of slope coefficients that I calculate from multiple treatments and controls from multiple studies. I'm looking at the relationship between *x* broadly and *y* broadly, with a null hypothesis of 0 slope. Because many studies report different more specific qualitatively different levels of *x* that I don't care to distinguish, I sometimes have several opportunities per study to get a slope for this relationship (e.g. in study *i* there may be vectors for $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, and $y_2$; therefore 4 slopes and SE's: $x_1*y_1, x_1*y_2, x_2*y_1, x_2*y_2$. Or study *i* may only have $x_1$ and $y_1$ for one slope and SE). Therefore my effect sizes and their sampling errors are not independent. This is a very similar problem to that addressed in [Gleser and Olkin](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:gleser2009), by [Lajeunnesse](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1890/11-0423.1) and in this [post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2018-April/000749.html).

**Problem**

The main twist is that I have correlations between not only one but both treatments I'm comparing via this slope effect size (since it's simply the same data used twice).  The above all give similar solutions to the usual problem of a shared control compared to multiple treatments, so I would try something similar to this ([copied](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2018-April/000762.html) verbatim, and the Lajeunnesse paper has the same thing in equation 8 but not in R code):

**Approach**

```
   calc.v <- function(x) {
  v <- matrix(x$SD_C[1]^2 / (x$N_C[1] * x$X_C[1]^2), nrow=nrow(x), ncol=nrow(x))
   #SD_C is SD for control,       
    #N_C is the n for the control, 
    #X_C is the response for the control, 
  diag(v) <- x$vi
   v
}

V <- bldiag(lapply(split(dat, dat$commonControl_ID), calc.v)) #this then can be used as a variance-covariance matrix instead of a sampling error vector in R's metafor rma.mv function.
```

**Question**

The diagonals stay the same, my sampling variances. How do I calculate the  covariance matrix to replace the off-diagonals in the matrix formula above with something that makes sense for some effect sizes sharing treatments and some sharing "controls?" Also I have SE of a slope with which to calculate sampling variances instead of SD's for different treatments.